# Oracle APEX Tabular form: Insert Only

Tags: oracle-apex

How do I create a Tabular Form with only Insert Option? When the user login, he should only Inset records and Save them. Existing records in the table should not be shown in the Tabular form. Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the tabular form into an Interactive Grid (APEX 5.0+) then this is trivially easy:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My question is why would you do this?
I would do a form and a report and hide the edit tab.
But that leads me to ask what if a user wants to edit a record?